# File I/O error using nglview.show_biopython(structure)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, bioinformatics, biopython

So I have been trying to get into visualizing proteins in python, so I went on youtube and found some tutorials I ended up on a tutorial that was teaching you how to visualize a protein from the COVID-19 virus, so I went and setup anaconda, got jupyter notebook working vscode, and downloaded the necessary files from the PDB database, and made sure they were in the same directory as my notebook but when I run the the nglview.show_biopython(structure) function I get an ValueError: I/O opertation on a closed file. I'm stummed this is my first time using jupyter notebook so maybe there is something I'm missing, I don't know.

This what the code looks like

```
from Bio.PDB import * 
import nglview as nv


parser = PDBParser()
structure = parser.get_structure("6YYT", "6YYT.pdb")
view = nv.show_biopython(structure)
```

This is the error

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1728\2743687014.py in <module>
----> 1 view = nv.show_biopython(structure)

c:\Users\jerem\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nglview\show.py in show_biopython(entity, **kwargs)
    450     '''
    451     entity = BiopythonStructure(entity)
--> 452     return NGLWidget(entity, **kwargs)
    453 
    454 

c:\Users\jerem\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nglview\widget.py in __init__(self, structure, representations, parameters, **kwargs)
    243         else:
    244             if structure is not None:
--> 245                 self.add_structure(structure, **kwargs)
    246 
    247         if representations:

c:\Users\jerem\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nglview\widget.py in add_structure(self, structure, **kwargs)
   1111         if not isinstance(structure, Structure):
   1112             raise ValueError(f'{structure} is not an instance of Structure')
-> 1113         self._load_data(structure, **kwargs)
   1114         self._ngl_component_ids.append(structure.id)
   1115         if self.n_components > 1:
...
--> 200         return io_str.getvalue()
    201 
    202 

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I only get this error when using nglview.show_biopython, when I run the get_structure() function it can read the file just fine. I can visualize other molucles just fine, or maybe that's because I was using the ASE library instead of a file. I don't know, that's why I'm here.

Update: Recently I found out that I can visualize the protein using nglview.show_file() instead of using nglview.show_biopython(). Even though I can visualize proteins now and techincally my problem has been solved I would still like to know why the show_biopython() function isn't working properly.

Comment: your prob is gettin me mad, !!!! Got same behaviour using io_pdb = PDBIO() io_pdb.set_structure(structurez) io_str = StringIO() io_pdb.save(io_str), io_str.getvalue() but only inside jupiter otherwise getting structure back from StringIO works fine .......

Comment: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9168   ValueError: I/O operation on closed file #9168

Comment: @pippo1980 so if I understand this correctly the reason I'm getting this error has something to do with ipython/ipykernel, if so what do I do about that? Do I have to change the version or something?

Comment: No idea, dont use jupiter at all, was just intrigued by your question. Nglview.demo() works though. Have you tried tempfile / memory file of sort ? I downgraded jupiter <8 but getting same results

Comment: @pippo1980 Well for one, if I can, how do I use nglview without jupyter notebook? If I knew that was an option I would have never even bother with trying to use jupyter or anaconda in the first play. I only installed anaconda because nglview didn't work when I used my current python installion as a kernel. I used jupyer notebook in vscode because nglview wouldn't work in a .py file. Second I don't know what a tempfile or a memory file is. Most of my python knowledge is centered around task automation and game developement, I have never heard of tempfile or memory files.

Comment: Try to chase Matteo Ferla on Bioinformatics stack exchsnge  think he is developing stuff on nglview, he is usually very kind. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tempfile.html its a library that help creating temp file not sure its a way to go for your stuff instead of StringIO.  I would be intrigued by use of BytesIO but is not accepted by PDBIO.

Comment: yep, think I'll need to change PDBIO.save to use other than file handlers or string, or not ?

Answer (score 3):

I also figured out another way to fix this problem. After going back to the tutorial I was talking about I saw that it was made back in 2021. After seeing this I wonder if we were using the same verions of each package, turns out we were not. I'm not sure what version of nglview they were using, but they were using biopython 1.79 which was the latest verion back in 2021 and I was using biopython 1.80. While using biopython 1.80 I was getting the error seen above. But now that I'm using biopython 1.79 I get this:

```python
file = "6YYT.pdb"
parser = PDBParser()
structure = parser.get_structure("6YYT", file)
structure

view = nv.show_biopython(structure)
view
```

###### Output:

```
c:\Users\jerem\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\PDB\StructureBuilder.py:89:
PDBConstructionWarning: WARNING: Chain A is discontinuous at line 12059.
  warnings.warn(
```

[image]

So I guess there is something going on with biopython 1.80, so I'm going to stick with 1.79

Comment: yep, same happens with my error, it goes away if I use biopython 1.79

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with:

```
from Bio.PDB import * 
import nglview as nv


parser = PDBParser(QUIET = True)
structure = parser.get_structure("2ms2", "2ms2.pdb")

save_pdb = PDBIO()
save_pdb.set_structure(structure)
save_pdb.save('pdb_out.pdb')

view = nv.show_biopython(structure)
view
```

error was like in question:

```
.................site-packages/nglview/adaptor.py:201, in BiopythonStructure.get_structure_string(self)
    199 io_str = StringIO()
    200 io_pdb.save(io_str)
--> 201 return io_str.getvalue()

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I modified `site-packages/nglview/adaptor.py:201, in  BiopythonStructure.get_structure_string(self)`:

```
def get_structure_string(self):
        from Bio.PDB import PDBIO
        from io import StringIO
        io_pdb = PDBIO()
        io_pdb.set_structure(self._entity)
        io_str = StringIO()
        io_pdb.save(io_str)
        return io_str.getvalue()
```

with :

```
def get_structure_string(self):
        from Bio.PDB import PDBIO
        
        import mmap
        
        io_pdb = PDBIO()
        
        io_pdb.set_structure(self._entity)
        
        mo = mmap_str()
        
        io_pdb.save(mo)
        
        return mo.read()
```

and added this new class `mmap_str()` , in same file:

```
import mmap
import copy

class mmap_str():

    import mmap #added import at top
    
    instance = None

    def __init__(self):
    
        self.mm = mmap.mmap(-1, 2)
        
        self.a = ''
        
        b = '\n'
        
        self.mm.write(b.encode(encoding = 'utf-8'))
        
        self.mm.seek(0)
        
        #print('self.mm.read().decode() ',self.mm.read().decode(encoding = 'utf-8'))
        
        self.mm.seek(0)
        
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(cls.instance, cls):
            cls.instance = object.__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance
        
    def write(self, string):
        
        self.a = str(copy.deepcopy(self.mm.read().decode(encoding = 'utf-8'))).lstrip('\n')
        
        self.mm.seek(0)
        
        #print('a -> ', self.a)
        
        len_a = len(self.a)
        
        self.mm = mmap.mmap(-1, len(self.a)+len(string))
        
        #print('a :', self.a)
        
        #print('len self.mm ', len(self.mm))
        
        #print('lenght string : ', len(string))
        
        #print(bytes((self.a+string).encode()))
        
        self.mm.write(bytes((self.a+string).encode()))
        
        self.mm.seek(0)
        
        #print('written once ')
        
        #self.mm.seek(0)
        
    def read(self):
    
        self.mm.seek(0)
        
        a = self.mm.read().decode().lstrip('\n')
        
        self.mm.seek(0)
        
        return a
        
    def __enter__(self):
        
        return self
 
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        
        pass
```

if I uncomment the print statements I'll get the :

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
```

error , but commenting them out I get:

[image]

while using the`nglview.show_file(filename)` I get:

[image]

tha's because, as could be seen looking at the `pdb_out.pdb` file

outputted by my code, `Biopytho.PDB.PDBParser.get_structure(name , filename)` doesnt retrieve the pdb header responsible for generate full CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC SYMMETRY/or biopython can't handle it (not sure about this, help if you know better),  but just the coordinates.

Still don't understand what is going on with the :

```
--> 201 return io_str.getvalue()

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

it could be something related to jupiter ipykernal ? hope somebody could shed more light into this, dont know how the framework runs, but is definitely different from a normal python interpreter. As an example:

[image]

Same code in one of my Python virtualenv, will run forever, so it could be ipykernel dont like `StringIO()`s or do something strange to them ?

OK thanks to the hint in the answer below, I went inspecting PDBIO.py in github repo for version Biopython 1.80 and compared the save method of PDBIO : [def save(self, file, select=_select, write_end=True, preserve_atom_numbering=False):](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/5ffdce852ba3721ca945ec383a69382507b4fa1b/Bio/PDB/PDBIO.py#L299) with the one in Biopython 1.79,

see first bit:
[image]

and last bit:
[image]

so apparently the big difference is the `with fhandle:` block in version 1.80.

So I realized that changing `adaptor.py` with adding a subclass of `StringIO` that looks like:

```
from io import StringIO
class StringIO(StringIO):

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        print('exiting from subclassed StringIO !!!!!')
        
        pass
```

and modifying `def get_structure_string(self):` like this:

```
def get_structure_string(self):
        from Bio.PDB import PDBIO
        #from io import StringIO
        io_pdb = PDBIO()
        io_pdb.set_structure(self._entity)
        io_str = StringIO()
        io_pdb.save(io_str)
        return io_str.getvalue()
```

was enough to get my Biopython 1.80 work in jupiter with nglview.

That told I am not sure what are the pitfalls of not closing the StringIO object we use for the visualization, but apparently its what Biopython 1.79 was doing like my first answer using a mmap object was doing too (not closing the mmap_str)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the problem:

I tried to understand Git, I ended up with this, seems more coherent with the previous habits in the biopython project, but can't push it.

[image]

It makes use of `as_handle` from `BIO.file` :https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/e1902d1cdd3aa9325b4622b25d82fbf54633e251/Bio/File.py#L28

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def as_handle(handleish, mode="r", **kwargs):
    r"""Context manager to ensure we are using a handle.
    Context manager for arguments that can be passed to SeqIO and AlignIO read, write,
    and parse methods: either file objects or path-like objects (strings, pathlib.Path
    instances, or more generally, anything that can be handled by the builtin 'open'
    function).
    When given a path-like object, returns an open file handle to that path, with provided
    mode, which will be closed when the manager exits.
    All other inputs are returned, and are *not* closed.
    Arguments:
     - handleish  - Either a file handle or path-like object (anything which can be
                    passed to the builtin 'open' function, such as str, bytes,
                    pathlib.Path, and os.DirEntry objects)
     - mode       - Mode to open handleish (used only if handleish is a string)
     - kwargs     - Further arguments to pass to open(...)
    Examples
    --------
    >>> from Bio import File
    >>> import os
    >>> with File.as_handle('seqs.fasta', 'w') as fp:
    ...     fp.write('>test\nACGT')
    ...
    10
    >>> fp.closed
    True
    >>> handle = open('seqs.fasta', 'w')
    >>> with File.as_handle(handle) as fp:
    ...     fp.write('>test\nACGT')
    ...
    10
    >>> fp.closed
    False
    >>> fp.close()
    >>> os.remove("seqs.fasta")  # tidy up
    """
    try:
        with open(handleish, mode, **kwargs) as fp:
            yield fp
    except TypeError:
        yield handleish
```

Anyone could pass it along? [Of course it needs to be checked out, my tests are OK, but I am a novice].